# Calling an API with props from navigation

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to call an API to my content management system based on values sent through navigation like so:

`final Map option = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;`

If i try to access the nav arguments in `initState()` it throws

`[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_ModalScopeStatus>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _SelfCareScreenState.initState() completed.`

If I access it in `didChangeDependencies()` it works, but calls the API twice. Is there a way I can call my api using `option` from nav arugments without calling it twice?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to send some kind of analytics (or something like that) you should look at [RouterObserver](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html) and [RouteAware](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RouteAware-class.html) classes. Depends on your needs maybe you should give a try to [NavigatorObserver](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/NavigatorObserver-class.html) with extended route information.

Comment: I'm trying to call an api that retrieves a specific set of content i.e. related articles with a variable that I'm passing through navigation, and I want it to call the api when the navigation occurs, or when the page loads. Thanks for your tip tho I'll keep that in mind when I'm implementing usage analytics

Comment: Then why don't just pass these variables to widget constructor? Is there a reason for not doing that?

Comment: Also, using `NavigatorObserver`, I think, it's possible to achieve what you want. But it's all look very complex to such a simple problem.